Get Graph API access token using Python
I am trying to replicate the instance of getting an access token that is used in the Microsoft Graph Explorer on the web. I had a look at the request that it makes. I have attached the following which I converted from curl to python.

import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://developer.microsoft.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'https://developer.microsoft.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}

data = 'client_id=de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fgraph%2Fgraph-explorer&scope=openid%20profile%20User.Read%20offline_access&code=vW3k&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=3.10.0&x-ms-lib-capability=retry-after, h429&x-client-current-telemetry=5|862,0,,,|,&x-client-last-telemetry=5|0|862,018f6224-a10e-73ae-b32d-a10aeab7b49b|user_cancelled|1,0&code_verifier=zpUdixfdLj4CsnhptxSZio&grant_type=authorization_code&client_info=1&client-request-id=018f6226-77e8-9028-ae2685da3b62&claims=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%7B%22xms_cc%22%3A%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%22CP1%22%5D%7D%7D%7D&X-AnchorMailbox=Oid%3A7aed27cb-3dd1-45d8-8323-7d0387be5ce0%4057c64fd4-66ca-49f5-ab38-2e67ef58e724'

response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', headers=headers, data=data)

It uses the following payload:
client_id: de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064
redirect_uri: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
scope: openid profile User.Read offline_access
code: 0.AQYA1E_GV8pm9UmrOC5n71jnJLXIi9752bFIqK23SNpyUGQGAMQ.xxxx
x-client-SKU: msal.js.browser
x-client-VER: 3.10.0
x-ms-lib-capability: retry-after, h429
x-client-current-telemetry: 5|862,0,,,|,
x-client-last-telemetry: 5|0|862,018f6224-xxxx-xxxx-b32d-a10aeab7b49b|user_cancelled|1,0
code_verifier: zpUdixfdLxhmpxxxx
grant_type: authorization_code
client_info: 1
client-request-id: 018f6226-xxx-xxx-xxx-ae2685da3b62
claims: {"access_token":{"xms_cc":{"values":["CP1"]}}}
X-AnchorMailbox: Oid:7aed27cb-xxx-xxx-8323-7d0387be5ce0@57c64fd4-66ca-xxxx-xxxx-2e67ef58e724

This is not working for me. It is throwing an error. b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.. How do I dynamically get the access token without using the refresh token. I don't have client secret. I have MFA on my account which means I need to I need approve the login from my microsot authenticator by entering a number displayed.


You are using authorization code as grant type to acquire the token. For that, you need to get code first but you can use it only once. To get the token, you need to get the authorization code again.

@Sridevi can you please help with the code to get that from Python?

So, your requirement is to get access token using authorization code in Python right?

@Sridevi yes but I don't have client secret. I am trying to get the access token for graph so I can read my sharepoint list items

If you don't have client secret, you can go with device code flow as I mentioned in your previous ask, will add the answer with modified code.

@Sridevi sure can you please share the modified code? I can try it out

@Sridevi I have added a  photo to show permission for reference in case you wanted it. I don't have admin privileges

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Initially, register one multi-tenant application with "Supported account type" as below:

To list items in SharePoint site, make sure to assign Sites.Read.All permission of "Delegated" type in application as below:

To avoid using client secret in code, make sure to enable public client flow option in your application like this:

Now, make use of below sample python code to acquire Graph API access token using device code flow:
import msal

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
client_id = "appId"
scopes = ["Sites.Read.All"]

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=client_id, authority=authority)

result = None
flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=scopes)
if "user_code" not in flow:
    print(flow.get("error"))
    print(flow.get("error_description"))
    raise ValueError("Couldn't create device flow")
else:
    print(flow["message"])
    result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    print("Access token acquired successfully:", access_token)
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))

When you run the code sample, it will show one message with link and device code like this:

Clicking on the link opens browser and asks you to enter device code as below:

In the Next step, it will ask you to sign in with Azure account which involves MFA prompt like this:

Once the authentication is successful, you can check the output console where access token will be generated like this:

To confirm that, you can decode this access token by pasting it in jwt.ms website and check scp claim:

When I used this token by running below sample python code, I got the response having list of items in SharePoint site like this:
import requests

access_token = 'your_access_token'
site_id = 'your_site_id'
list_id = 'your_list_id'

graph_endpoint = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(graph_endpoint, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    for item in data['value']:
        print(item)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve items from SharePoint list.")
    print("Status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response body:", response.text)

Response:

Reference:
Retrieve items from a SharePoint list - Microsoft Graph v1.0

AADSTS70002: The provided client is not supported for this feature. The client application must be marked as 'mobile.' Trace ID: ed474425-d3c3-4093-971a-1d5c1eaeb500 Correlation ID: 01cfa12e-52a9-48df-8f39-211a96f389f2 Timestamp: 2024-05-10 14:48:19Z I get the following error

This error occurs if that public client setting is not enabled for your application as I mentioned in discussion. Ask your admin to enable that setting for application
